# VS2017 python plotly

Tags: python, plotly, visual-studio-2017

Trying to learn python with VS2017 Committee on Win10. Console apps worked ok. So for my next project, I installed Bottle and messed around with the sample project.

In researching questions, came across plotly, so I wanted to try that.

In VS2017, I went to Environments -> Packages and installed via "pip install plotly" from PyPI. The output showed that installed ok.

However I get errors when I hit the "import plotly.plotly as py"

Thinking it was the VS environment, I started a console, did "pip install plotly --upgrade" and no errors.

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import plotly
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a chance that you installed `plotly` for python-2.x and not for python-3.x which you are using - try specifying to pip which python's version `plotly` to install...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an error I didn't notice. Error was a permissions related, so I ran install as an Admin and it went ok. Then I restarted VS as Admin, and did the install again and it's working in Bottle as well.

> 'C:\Users\marten\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-dgsnu4v8-uninstall\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main status = self.run(options, args)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run prefix=options.prefix_path,
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 778, in install requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove renames(path, new_path)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 267, in renames shutil.move(old, new)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 550, in move
>       rmtree(src)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 488, in rmtree
>       return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 383, in _rmtree_unsafe
>       onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 381, in _rmtree_unsafe
>       os.unlink(fullname)
>
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\cli.py